# XSL-FO: How to set initial page number for whole document?

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

My xml is root with many different child element in any order, each with its own markup inside `page-sequence`. Xslt template takes one param - initial page of this document. And I cant set it in `initial-page-number` attribute for `page-sequence` because dont know which element will be first. Is there any workarounds in xsl-fo or xslt level for applying given number as page number of first page-sequence?

xml example 1:

```
<root>
 <item-abc/>
 <item-def/>
 <item-ghj/>
</root>
```

xml example 2:

```
<root>
 <item-ghj/>
 <item-ghj/>
 <item-abc/>
</root>
```

xslt:

```
<x:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <x:template match="/">
  <fo:root text-align="center" font-family="Arial" font-size="9pt">
    <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="m" margin-left="7mm" margin-right="9mm" margin-top="8mm" margin-bottom="1mm" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm">
            <fo:region-body margin-top="14mm" margin-left="2mm"/>
            <fo:region-before />
            <fo:region-after />
        </fo:simple-page-master>
    </fo:layout-master-set>
   <x:apply-templates select="root/item-abc"/>
   <x:apply-templates select="root/item-def"/>
   <x:apply-templates select="root/item-ghj"/>
  </fo:root>
 </x:template>

 <x:template match="root/item-abc">
  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="m" format="00001">
   ....
  </fo:page-sequence>
 </x:template>

 ...another items' templates
</x:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal excerpt from your XML and XSLT.  We don't know what your XSLT template looks like, so it's hard for us to help you change it.

Comment: @TonyGraham done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> because dont know which element will be first.

If it is true, change the follwoing your code

```
<x:apply-templates select="root/item-abc"/>
<x:apply-templates select="root/item-def"/>
<x:apply-templates select="root/item-ghj"/>
```

to

```
<x:apply-templates select="root/*"/>
```

And check which is first by `position()` function:

```
<x:template match="root/item-abc">
   <fo:page-sequence master-reference="m" format="00001">
       <x:if test="position() eq 1">
           <x:attribute name="initial-page-number" select="'1'"/>
       </x:if>
   ....
   </fo:page-sequence>
</x:template>
```

This will satisfy your requirement.